# I made a random number generator, is it good enough or can I make it more randomized?

Tags: math, random, lua

```lua
local z = 50 -- you can change this to the maximum value

local function ARN() -- function starts
local x = math.random(0,z) -- main number
local y = math.random() -- decimal number
local v = (x-(y)) -- I remove y's value from x
print(v) -- I then print it
return v, x, y -- return the values
end

ARN() -- calling the function
```

I basically made it random with decimal numbers too. I don't know if there is anything to make it more randomized.
Also, I'm new to programming, so maybe some tips could be helpful too!

Comment: I would add something related with the current timestamp so that even if it's called three times in a row, the seed is different.  In fact, three times in parallel + `random()` will create different seeds too (so more randomized?)

Comment: You don't need the parentheses for `v = x - y`. Your comments are just repeating the code and thus pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`math.random()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.random) already returns a floating-point random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). You apparently want a floating-point random number from 0 to `z`. Simply "scaling" the random by multiplying it with `z` should be fully sufficient and only takes a single call to `math.random`:

```lua
local function ARN() return math.random() * z end
```

This may slightly decrease randomness in the floating point part, but for small `z` it shouldn't be noticeable.

Your implementation currently is from 0 (exclusive) to `z` (inclusive). In practice this probably matters rarely, but are these the intended bounds? The scaling I have presented would be consistent with `math.random`, with 0 being exclusive and `z` being inclusive.

As for "randomness": `math.random` uses [xoshiro256**](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/a-quick-look-at-xoshiro256.html) and you're pretty much just using `math.random`, so you should have about the same randomness. It's just a "pseudo" and not a "secure" random though.

Also consider seeding the random using `math.randomseed(os.time() + os.clock())` or the like; note that the seed is global and whether you want to seed it depends on your application (you might want a fixed seed for testing purposes f.E.).